# Index help Java

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering if there's a way to get an index, let me show you an example.

```
String[] names = {"Daniel", "Lewis", "Sarah", "John"};

   String cmd = input.nextLine();

  String CMD[] = cmd.split(" ");


  if (CMD[0].equalsIgnoreCase("my name is") && CMD[1].equalsIgnoreCase(accountIndex[0])){

     System.out.println("My name is Daniel!");

  } else if (CMD[0].equalsIgnoreCase("my name is") && CMD[1].equalsIgnoreCase(accountIndex[1])) {

     System.out.println("My name is Lewis!");
  } else if (CMD[0].equalsIgnoreCase("my name is") && CMD[1].equalsIgnoreCase(accountIndex[2])) {

     System.out.println("My name is Sarah!");
  } else if (CMD[0].equalsIgnoreCase("my name is") && CMD[1].equalsIgnoreCase(accountIndex[3])) {

     System.out.println("My name is John!");
  }
```

Is there an easier way to do this, than nesting if statements?

Please note, I'd only want to use names inside of the table, so I can't just make a String called myName equal to CMD[1].

I suppose it's sort of like a database of usernames, if your username doesn't exist, you can't log in.

I want it like that, but without nesting loads of if statements, and the names Array would be the database in this instance.

Comment: accountIndex will be replaced by names

Comment: Could you give more information on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sure, if you want to know what I am actually trying to do with this, it'd be like an email system. So you'd do !email somenamefromtable texthere and if the name was valid, it'd say "Email sent to [Name from Array] then the text could be "This is a test"

Comment: What is accountIndex?

Comment: Considering you split upon a space, there is no way for the strings in `CMD` to have a space.

Comment: That was the String array called names, I just made it easier to understand by renaming it to names, instead of accountIndex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Daniel", "Lewis", "Sarah", "John");
if (names.contains(CMD[3]) {
    System.out.println("My name is " + CMD[0]);
} else {
    // not found...
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong... The array should start at CMD[3] because there will be elements: a[0] = "my", a[1]="name", and a[2] = "is".

Comment: Invalid code posted by OP doesnt help - corrected :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length(); i++) {
    if (CMD[3].equalsIgnoreCase(accountIndex[i])) {
        System.out.println("My name is " + names[i] + "!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 This will not work because CMD is an array created by the split function which splits all strings with spaces. Therefore no element will have spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Running `cmd.split()` will split the array giving you an array: `{"my", "name", "is", "some_name"}`. Which means that the name you want to check will be given at the fourth element in the array hence index `[3]`.

```
String[] names = {"Daniel", "Lewis", "Sarah", "John"};

String cmd = input.nextLine();
String CMD[] = cmd.split(" ");

// Initial check to see if my name is exists.
if(cmd.subtstring(0, 10).equalsIgnoreCase("my name is") && cmd.length > 3)
{
    // This loop is better than checking each individual case because it allows you to dynamically add elements to your names array
    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
    {
        // Must start at the fourth element since my, name, and is will be the 0-2 elements.
        if(CMD[3].equalsIgnoreCase(names[i]))
        {
            System.out.println("My name is "+names[i]+"!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting on a space, so

```
CMD[0].equalsIgnoreCase("my name is")
```

will never evaluate to true.

Why are you testing for `"my name is "` at all? Just capture the fourth word, if that is the format you're using: `CMD[3]`.

To avoid these if-else-if-elses, put the names into a Map where the key is the name, and the value is always `null`.

Then test the name against the keys:

```
if(mapOfNames.containsKey(CMD[3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the valid usernames in a TreesSet and then when user enters a name you can lookup the TreeSet to test if the given name is a valid name.

```
TreeSet<String> validNames = new TreeSet<String>();
validNames.add("John");
validNames.add("Mary");
.....
.....

// For searching
if(validNames.contains(CMD[0]))
{
 // name exists
}
else{
   // invalid name
}
```

Note : You can store the names in any searchable collection (HashMaps are also a good choice for this scenario. This is just a pointer and you need to deep dig to find which Data structure suits your need. For more information you can refer the following links :

[TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

[HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert array to list and then search for the name in the list with `contains` method:

```
if(Arrays.asList(names).contains(CMD[3]))
    System.out.println("My name is " + CMD[3] + "!");
```

Comment: This will not work. because no elements in the array will have spaces.

Comment: @RyanDawkins Sorry, my bad. I just directly concentrated on OP's problem without seeing his fault on "my name is" comparison. Thank you.